# Swift displaying image in viewdidappear cannot be replaced by picking new image

Tags: swift

I use firebase as my back end and I have a displaying facebook photo image function in viewdidappear so the profile image will display when the user is at the viewcontroller. My problem is whenever user want to change the profile Image by image picker it will display the "picked image" for 1 sec only and turn back to facebook image.

I think the problem is the displaying facebook photo image function is in the viewdidappear? How can I solve it?

```
override func viewdidappear(){
  super.viewdidappear(animated)
  self.displayProfilePic(user)
}

func displayProfilePic(user: FIRUser?){

let photoURL = user?.photoURL
struct last {
  static var photoURL: NSURL? = nil
} 
last.photoURL = photoURL;  later one.
if let photoURL = photoURL {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    let data = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: photoURL)
    if let data = data {
      let image = UIImage.init(data: data)
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if (photoURL == last.photoURL) {
          self.profilePic.image = image

        }
      })
    }

  })
} else {
  profilePic.image = UIImage.init(named: "DefaultPic")
}
```

image Picker method

```
  func openGallary(){

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
  print("Pick Photo")

  self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
  self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
  self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

func openCamera(){
if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
  self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
  self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
  self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}else{
  print("you got no camara")
}
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMeddiaWithInfo info: [String :AnyObject]){
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

  profilePic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
  profilePic.image = pickedImage
}
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am not sure why the image picker's picked image cannot be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is the displaying facebook photo image function is in the viewdidappear

This is correct. `viewDidAppear` is called every time the view is shown again after a VC that was covering it is dismissed (e.g. the image picker).

You could do this in `viewDidLoad` instead -- which is called just once when the VC is loaded -- and is not called again when the imagePicker is done.

If you can't, then you need to keep track that the imagePicker replaced the image and that it should not be replaced again with the FB image when `viewDidAppear` is called.

Comment: I have put the method in  viewDidLoad instead but it is not working and i had tried before.

Comment: Follow the instructions after "If you can't, then ..." in my answer